# Getting HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request[\r][\n]

Tags: java

**getting bad request when I sent "/" character in the request body of POST method**

```
    HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
    PostMethod postMethod = new PostMethod(kairosDBUrl);

    RequestEntity requestEntity = null;

    try {
        requestEntity = new StringRequestEntity(inputBody, "text/json", "UTF-8");
        postMethod.setRequestEntity(requestEntity);
        client.executeMethod(postMethod);
        responseBody = IOUtils.toString(postMethod.getResponseBodyAsStream(), postMethod.getResponseCharSet());
    } catch (IOException e) {
        LOG.error("Unexpected exception : {}", e);
    } finally{
        postMethod.releaseConnection();
    }
```

**Input:**

```
{metrics=[{name=apache.Activity_Bytes/req, tags={host=[ip-10-0-0-201]}, aggregators=[{name=avg, align_sampling=true, sampling={value=5, unit=seconds}}]}], cache_time=0, start_absolute=1496222264000, end_absolute=1496224064000}
```

**Error:**

```
"{"errors":["com.google.gson.stream.MalformedJsonException: Unterminated object at line 1 column 39"]}"
```

Comment: It's just a wild guess but did you try to escape the slash with a backslash infront of it?

Comment: Your JSON is not valid, you should correct it.

Comment: The JSON is complete crap - sorry. Try http://json-validator.com/ to correct your input.

Comment: When ever I gave name without "/" in the input, it worked.

Answer (score 0):

Usually the "Bad Request" status comes out when you're trying to invoke a method with something that the method isn't able to handle.

In this case you get this exception

```
["com.google.gson.stream.MalformedJsonException: Unterminated object at line 1 column 39"]
```

that tells you that your .json file needs to be fixed.
My suggestion is to check if your Json file's structure matches with your Entity's structure.

Comment: I tried with same input json without "/" character. I got response too.

Comment: @madhukarreddy So what makes you think the "/" is the root cause of your problem (instead of your completely invalid JSON)?

Comment: In the error itself it showing the line 1 and column 39. ["com.google.gson.stream.MalformedJsonException: Unterminated object at line 1 column 39"]

Answer (score 0):

**By mistake I supposed to use json.toString() but I used map.toString() which is returning invalid String.**

map.toString() worked when it doesn't have special characters, but it did not work when it has special characters.